# Oracle - How to filter out duplicate rows without using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
select
   C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, C.MODIFIEDDATE, V.NAME
from TPM_PROJECTCHANGES C
inner join TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ON C.PROJECTID = V.PROJECTID AND C.VERSIONID = V.VERSIONID
where C.MODIFIEDDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/18/12', 'MM/DD/YY') and TO_DATE('07/25/12', 'MM/DD/YY')
```

I want to show all changes in a project between certain dates.  This works fine.  However, I have a lot of duplicates (such as if someone changed the same attribute on the same project 50 times).  I want to filter those out and only show the most recent time a certain attribute was changed on the project.  I can do something like this:

```
select
   C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, MAX(C.MODIFIEDDATE)
from TPM_PROJECTCHANGES C
having MAX(C.MODIFIEDDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/18/12', 'MM/DD/YY') and TO_DATE('07/25/12', 'MM/DD/YY')
group by C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID
```

However, now I can't `JOIN` anything in.  For example, if I try:

```
select
   C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, MAX(C.MODIFIEDDATE), V.NAME
from TPM_PROJECTCHANGES C
inner join TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ON C.PROJECTID = V.PROJECTID AND C.VERSIONID = V.VERSIONID
having MAX(C.MODIFIEDDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/18/12', 'MM/DD/YY') and TO_DATE('07/25/12', 'MM/DD/YY')
group by C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID
```

I'll get the error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Is there a better way to filter out duplicate changes to the same project?

Comment: Try moving `having` after `group_by`

Comment: @rogal111 - The position of `HAVING` makes no difference.  It seems Oracle (or SQL) doesn't support this, even though it logically makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use analytic functions:

```
select PROJECTID, VERSIONID, MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, MODIFIEDDATE, Name
from (select C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, C.MODIFIEDDATE, V.NAME,
             row_number() over (partition by C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, V.NAME
                                order by C.MODIFIEDDATE desc) as seqnum
      from TPM_PROJECTCHANGES C inner join
           TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ON C.PROJECTID = V.PROJECTID AND C.VERSIONID = V.VERSIONID
      where C.MODIFIEDDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/18/12', 'MM/DD/YY') and
                                   TO_DATE('07/25/12', 'MM/DD/YY')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: `+1` for the only working answer so far, however it seems like this is going to get very complicated very quickly, as I add more columns in.  I'm worried about perf as well.  I'll accept this if no better answers are posted.

Answer (score 1):

The `HAVING` should be the last line on your query:

```
select
   C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, MAX(C.MODIFIEDDATE), V.NAME
from TPM_PROJECTCHANGES C
inner join TPM_PROJECTVERSION V 
ON C.PROJECTID = V.PROJECTID AND C.VERSIONID = V.VERSIONID
group by C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, V.NAME
having MAX(C.MODIFIEDDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/18/12', 'MM/DD/YY') and TO_DATE('07/25/12', 'MM/DD/YY')
```

Comment: Doesn't matter where it is.  I get `not a GROUP BY expression` unless I remove the `V.NAME` from the `SELECT` list.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Added V.NAME to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental rule of *SQL query composition* is the following. Wrap your working SQl query in parenthesis, and inline it as a view:

```
select
   V.NAME, IC.* 
from (/*working query against TPM_PROJECTCHANGES here*/ ) IC
inner join TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ...
```

Regarding the syntax of your last query, group by list is expected to accommodate more columns, than your select clause, not less (excluding the aggregates, of course).

Comment: You're saying you *cannot* include values on JOIN'ed tables unless those columns are also in your `GROUP BY` list?  This is why I want to avoid `GROUP BY`: Because I'm joining in about 5 tables and including a *ton* of columns from those tables.

Comment: If you don't care about aggregation, why wouldn't DISTINCT suffice?

Comment: select distinct C.PROJECTID, C.VERSIONID, C.MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID, C.MODIFIEDDATE, V.NAME
      from TPM_PROJECTCHANGES C inner join
           TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ON C.PROJECTID = V.PROJECTID AND C.VERSIONID = V.VERSIONID
      where C.MODIFIEDDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/18/12', 'MM/DD/YY') and
                                   TO_DATE('07/25/12', 'MM/DD/YY')

Comment: I *do* care about aggregation.  I want to only show the latest time the property was updated.